# Why aren't my javaScript functions firing?

Tags: javascript, module, geolocation, appcelerator, data-retrieval

I can't figure out what is keeping my functions from firing. I'm coding on the Appcelerator Studio and have four js files I am pulling from. Here is the code for one of the functions that wont fire.

app.js file

```
    var ui = require("win");

    var geo = require("geo");
    geo.getGeo;
```

geo.js file

```
    var getGeo =  function() {
        console.log("Geo Module");
        Ti.Geoloaction.purpose = "Your location is needed to get your weather forecast.";
        Ti.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(a){
            console.log(a);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(a.source));
            var userLoc = {
                lat : a.cords.latitude,
                lng : a.cords.longitude
            };
        });
        //win.buildGeoUi;
        net.netFnc;
        console.log(userLoc.lat, userLoc.lng);
    };

    exports.getGeo = getGeo;
```

This is for a weather app for a school project. I am also trying to pull data from an api which is nested inside a function as well.

When I run my app the console.logs i have inside of my getGeo function are not running, this is how I know it is not firing the function.

Comment: you need some brackets to call the function `getGeo()`

Comment: Thank You! I knew it was minor oversight but i just couldn't for the life of me figure it out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your are doing `geo.getGeo;` and you should do `geo.getGeo();` to execute the function.